# Regular expression - How do I only keep ABC12345 from a string ABC_ABC12345_ABC_ABC.txt, sometimes it can be ABC12345_ABC.txt

Tags: .net, regex

Regular expression - How do I only keep ABC12345 from a string ABC_ABC12345_ABC_ABC.txt, sometimes it can be ABC12345_ABC.txt

Comment: Can you include what your current regular expression is?

Comment: You simply specify the string in your regex, then you will get a match.

Answer (score 0):

You could RegEx search pattern `^.*_(\w+\d+)_.*$` to return the desired match.  This pattern assumes the desired match is wrapped in underscores, has alphanumeric prefix of one-to-many characters and ends in one-to-many numeric digits.

**UPDATE:** Revised Pattern to allow that the match might be at the beginning of the string and not preceded by underscore: `^(.*_|)(\w+\d+)_.*$`.  In this pattern, you would want to capture the second match.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing a lot about your match criteria (for example, it is just digits, any break via underscore, something else?), I'd say this might work:

```
string test = "ABC_ABC12345_ABC_ABC.txt";

Regex rx = new Regex(@"ABC\d+");
Match m = rx.Match(test);

if (m.Success)
    test = m.Groups[0].Value;
```

If you don't need it to replace the original string (you just need the result), just put it into a separate variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{   
    public static void Main()
    {
        string string1 = "ABC_ABC12345_ABC_ABC.txt";

        Regex s1 = new Regex(@"\w{3}\d{5}");
        //if just for capital letter and only three characters and five numbers use: Regex s2 = new Regex(@"[A-Z]{3}\d{5}");
        //if the number of characters "capital letter" and numbers does not matter use: Regex s2 = new Regex(@"[A-Z]+\d+");
        //if the number of characters "capital and small letter" and numbers does not matter use: Regex s2 = new Regex(@"[A-Za-z]+\d+"); 


        Regex s2 = new Regex(@"\w{3}\d{5}\w{8}\.\w{3}");
        //if just for capital letter and only three characters and five numbers use: Regex s2 = new Regex(@"[A-Z]{3}\d{5}_[A-Z]{3}_[A-Z]{3}\.\w{3}");
        //if the number of characters "capital letter" and numbers does not matter use: Regex s2 = new Regex(@"[A-Z]+\d+_[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+\.\w{3}");
        //if the number of characters "capital and small letter" and numbers does not matter use: Regex s2 = new Regex(@"[A-Za-z]+\d+_[A-Za-z]+_[A-Za-z]+\.\w{3}");


        Match m1 = s1.Match(string1);
        Match m2 = s2.Match(string1);


        if (m1.Success){
            String result = m1.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(result);  
        }
        else if(m2.Success){
            String result = m2.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        else{
           Console.WriteLine("No match");
        }
    }
}
```

After the test

[image]

I've commented the first condition, to validate the second condition

[image]